# Problem Solving a Differntial Inequality.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality

I am having problems solving the following differential inequality.
$$\begin{cases}\alpha r^2 f(r) - \frac{r^2 - \ell^2 M}{\ell^2}\left(f'(r)\right)^2 > 0\\
f(l \sqrt{M}) = 0
 \end{cases}, \qquad r> \ell\sqrt{M}>0$$
I tried to solve first for the equality obtaining,
$$ f(r) = \frac{\ell^2 \alpha}{4} \left( r^2 - \ell^2 M\right).$$
Then, I try to said that $$f(r) > \frac{\ell^2 \alpha}{4}(r^2 - \ell^2 M).$$
However, I am not sure if this is correct or if it exist another way to solve this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can do this way. The inequality is
$$ \frac{r^2 - \ell^2 M}{\ell^2}\left(f'(r)\right)^2 <\alpha r^2 f(r) $$
from which, one has $f(r)>0$ for $r>\ell\sqrt M$. So
$$ -\frac{\alpha r\ell}{\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}}<\frac{f'(r)}{\sqrt{f(r)}}<\frac{\alpha r\ell}{\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}}. $$
Integrating from $\ell\sqrt M$ to $r$ gives
$$ -\alpha\ell\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}\bigg|^{r}_{s=\ell\sqrt M}\le2\sqrt{f(s)}\bigg|^{r}_{s=\ell\sqrt M}\le\alpha\ell\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}\bigg|^{r}_{s=\ell\sqrt M} $$
or
$$ 0\le \sqrt{f(r)}\le \frac12\alpha\ell(\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}-\ell\sqrt{M-1}). $$
So
$$ 0\le f(r) \le \frac14\alpha^2\ell^2(\sqrt{r^2-\ell^2}-\ell\sqrt{M-1})^2. $$

Comment: Thanks, but I think that there are some things missing. When Integrate $\frac{f'(r)}{\sqrt{f(r)}}$, there should not appear a 2 after the integration. Also when it is took the square root $\alpha \rightarrow \sqrt{\alpha}$

Comment: Yes, your are right. Thanks.